# Регулярное выражение для поиска ссылки с классом

Tags: регулярные-выражения, html, php

Есть код html. В нём нужно найти ссылку у которой класс genmed. Помогите пожалуйста составить регулярное выражение. С регулярками вообще не дружу просто)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

простейший:

```
if(preg_match('/<a\s+href="([^\"]+)"[^\>]+class="genmed"/i',$value,$m))
     $URL = $m[1];
```

нет проверки на случай, когда class="genmed" стоит перед href - ну, тут если такое случается, дополнить условие еще одним if и не париться.

Да, можно написать супер-универсальный regexp, но я надеюсь, что для вашей задачи это подойдет.

Answer (score 2):

```
/<a[^>]*class="[^"]*genmed[^"]*"[^>]*>[^<]*<\/a>/
```

Примерно так, ща проверю, отпишу.

Проверил)

```
<?
$text = 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetuer turpis dictumst In sed pede. Sit sed massa volutpat lobortis urna feugiat platea enim id Pellentesque. Sit sem feugiat <a href="#" class="123 genmed lol">vitae</a> metus hendrerit urna eu Vestibulum risus penatibus. Maecenas Nulla pellentesque <a href="#">tellus</a> nunc gravida Vestibulum est facilisi turpis et justo. Et nonummy et <a href="#" class="lol">tellus</a> sem laoreet elit sociis tincidunt hac Phasellus. <a href="#" class="genmed">Mollis Mauris</a> massa in pellentesque non facilisis.';

preg_match_all('/<a[^>]*class="[^"]*genmed[^"]*"[^>]*>[^<]*<\/a>/', $text, $match);
var_dump($match);
?>

array(1) {
  [0]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    string(44) "<a href="#" class="123 genmed lol">vitae</a>"
    [1]=>
    string(44) "<a href="#" class="genmed">Mollis Mauris</a>"
  }
}
```